Impossible to change drag and dropped (with tkinterdnd2) raster when plotting
When running the following Python code, I'm able to change the raster (by drag and dropping a new raster file) and display its name in anew window as many times as I want (without closing the selection window and re-running the code). But as soon as I plot the raster distribution, I cannot change the raster file anymore. Which is what I want.
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinterdnd2 import TkinterDnD, DND_FILES
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import messagebox

class SimpleApp(TkinterDnD.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Simple File Selector")
        self.geometry("400x400")

        self.file_label = tk.Label(self, text="Drop a file here", relief="solid", width=40, height=5)
        self.file_label.pack(pady=20)
        self.file_label.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
        self.file_label.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', self.load_file)

        self.print_button = tk.Button(self, text="Display Filename", command=self.display_filename)
        self.print_button.pack(pady=20)

        self.plot_button = tk.Button(self, text="Plot Distribution", command=self.plot_distribution)
        self.plot_button.pack(pady=20)

    def load_file(self, event):
        self.file_path = event.data.strip('{}')
        self.file_label.config(text=os.path.basename(self.file_path) if self.file_path else "No file selected")
        try:
            with rasterio.open(self.file_path) as src:
                self.raster_data = src.read(1)
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to read raster file: {e}")
            self.file_label.config(text="Drop a file here")
            self.raster_data = None

    def display_filename(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'file_path') and self.file_path:
            filename_window = tk.Toplevel(self)
            filename_window.title("Selected File")
            filename_window.geometry("300x100")
            filename_label = tk.Label(filename_window, text=self.file_path, wraplength=280)
            filename_label.pack(pady=20)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "No file selected")

    def plot_distribution(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'raster_data') and self.raster_data is not None:
            plt.figure()
            plt.hist(self.raster_data.flatten(), bins=50, color='blue', edgecolor='black')
            plt.title('Raster Data Distribution')
            plt.xlabel('Value')
            plt.ylabel('Frequency')
            plt.show()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "No raster data to plot")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SimpleApp()
    app.mainloop()


Is matplotlib using tkinter or another backend? After you show the plot, if you drag a new file to the window, does it call the load_file method?

It is not clear what "cannot change the raster file anymore" means.

@TheLizzard: no the load_file method is not called.

Try adding import matplotlib and matplotlib.use('TkAgg') at the top of the file. If that still doesn't work, try using something like this.

Inspiring from TheLizzard link, I was able to fix the issue. Thanks to him.
Here is the fixed code:
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinterdnd2 import TkinterDnD, DND_FILES
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import messagebox
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class SimpleApp(TkinterDnD.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Simple File Selector")
        self.geometry("400x400")

        self.file_label = tk.Label(self, text="Drop a file here", relief="solid", width=40, height=5)
        self.file_label.pack(pady=20)
        self.file_label.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
        self.file_label.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', self.load_file)

        self.print_button = tk.Button(self, text="Display Filename", command=self.display_filename)
        self.print_button.pack(pady=20)

        self.plot_button = tk.Button(self, text="Plot Distribution", command=self.plot_distribution)
        self.plot_button.pack(pady=20)

        self.file_path = None
        self.raster_data = None

    def load_file(self, event):
        self.file_path = event.data.strip('{}')
        self.file_label.config(text=os.path.basename(self.file_path) if self.file_path else "No file selected")
        try:
            with rasterio.open(self.file_path) as src:
                self.raster_data = src.read(1)
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to read raster file: {e}")
            self.file_label.config(text="Drop a file here")
            self.raster_data = None

    def display_filename(self):
        if self.file_path:
            filename_window = tk.Toplevel(self)
            filename_window.title("Selected File")
            filename_window.geometry("300x100")
            filename_label = tk.Label(filename_window, text=self.file_path, wraplength=280)
            filename_label.pack(pady=20)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "No file selected")

    def plot_distribution(self):
        if self.raster_data is not None:
            plot_window = tk.Toplevel(self)
            plot_window.title("Raster Data Distribution")
            plot_window.geometry("800x600")

            fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=100)
            ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
            ax.hist(self.raster_data.flatten(), bins=50, color='blue', edgecolor='black')
            ax.set_title('Raster Data Distribution')
            ax.set_xlabel('Value')
            ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')

            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=plot_window)
            canvas.draw()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

            toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(plot_window)
            toolbar_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, toolbar_frame)
            toolbar.update()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "No raster data to plot")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SimpleApp()
    app.mainloop()

